# Password Grant Types, standard way to pass username and password

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In Oauth 2 Password Grant Type, when retrieving the access token, where should I pass the parameter like username, password and grant_type?

Is it as query param, in body or in header?

Answer (score 0):

Following OAuth 2.0 rules you'll pass them in the HTTP POST request entity-body using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Additionally, if the client application was issued client credentials in the form of a client ID and client secret you will pass those in an `Authorization` request header using the `Basic` authentication scheme.

This is stated in [section 4.3.2 of the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2).

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by adding the following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP request entity-body.

For doubts around the exact syntax of the requests you should always refer to the spec. For additional information, example code, you can always refer to the documentation of identity providers, like Auth0 and/or Google that implement these protocols.

Comment: Can you please give the relevant reference?